# Page Numbers not showing correctly in latex document

Tags: latex

I am very new to making documents in Latex and I need to write a report.
I have made a main.tex where in I call each chapter. I would like :

- for the declaration, acknowledgement, lift of figures and list of tables  to have roman page numbers
- introduction and following chapters to have arabic numbers

I have browsed the previous posts and found a bit of code but somehow my page numbers do not show. Page number is visible only on the Title Page and I do not want the Title Page to have any number.
Here is the code I currently have:

```
\documentclass{Thesis}
\input{import_packages.tex}
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\begin{document}
\input{titlepage.tex}

\frontmatter
\input{Declaration.tex}
\input{Acknowledgement.tex}


\input{TableOfContents.tex} 
\input{ListOfFigures.tex}   
\input{ListOfTables.tex}

\mainmatter
\input{Introduction.tex}    
\input{ProblemDescription.tex}
\input{BackgroundResearch.tex}
\input{DataPreprocessingAndPreparation.tex}
\input{AlgorithmAndApproach.tex}
\input{Implementation.tex}
\input{ExperimentalAndStatisticalResults.tex}
\input{Conclusion.tex}
\input{FutureScopeofWork.tex}   
\end{document}
```

I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: We can't compile your code!

Comment: You used '\pagenumbering{roman}' at the preamble. That applies to all the pages in your thesis report. Also you should provide compilable code. You included files we know nothing of.

Comment: @cs13 Please make a [mre] which we can compile without having access to the files on your computer. Please also link to the particular `Thesis` class you use, there are probably a zillion of those out in the internet.